# How can I delete data from two arrays?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, kendo-grid

I have a grid that shows the list of time (from time to time)

for example

```
timeList=[{from:12:00:00 , to:14:00:00 ,id:10}{from:08:00:00 , to:09:00:00 ,id:11{from:05:00:00 , to:10:00:00 ,id:12}}]

time=[{Value:12:00:00 id:10}
      {Value:14:00:00 id:100}
      {Value:08:00:00 id:11}
      {Value:09:00:00 id:110}
      {Value:05:00:00 id:12}
      {Value:10:00:00 id:15}
]
```

To delete an item I have this code

```
    deleteTimeView(data) {
////date ==>{from:12:00:00 , to:14:00:00 ,id:10}
        let indexOfDeleted = -1;
        let time = this.state.time;
        let timeList=this.state.timeList;
    
        this.state.time.forEach((item, index) => {
            if (item.Id === data.id) {
    
                indexOfDeleted = index;
    
            }
        })
        time.splice(indexOfDeleted, 1);
        time.splice(indexOfDeleted, 1);
     
        timeList.splice(indexOfDeleted, 1);
    
        this.setState({
    
            time: time,
            timeList: timeList
        });
    
    }
```

My problem is that when I want to delete id12, I have index 4, but I do not have this index in timeList.
I have no problem deleting that item in time, but how can I delete it from timeList as well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, don't use `.splice`, it mutates the array and in this case means you're directly mutating state. Never mutate the state in React.

Secondly, a simple filter approach based on the ID should satisfy your needs:

```
deleteTimeView(data) {
    this.setState({
        time: this.state.time.filter(t => t.id !== data.id),
        timeList: this.state.timeList.filter(t => t.id !== data.id)
    });
}
```